# how to change appliocation URL in IIS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis

My web application URL is

http://Domain.com/ParentVirtualDirName/ChildVirtualDirName/Controller/View

this is how i have configured in my local IIS.

Now when it goes for Quality Assurance the Url is

http://Domain.com/ChildVirtualDirName/Controller/View

They don't have Parent Vritual Directory name.

This causing relative path issue in many places 
Please let me know how to do it

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you actually are suffering from non-relative, or absolute, path issues. The answer is to find the path references (URLs beginning with / or http://.../) in your web application that are not relative and make them relative.